# PHP, Saving a String to Text. (fputs)

Tags: php, html

PHP

```
<?php
if ($changefile) {
    $savedEdit = stripslashes($_POST['filetest']);
    $filetochange = "../dashboard/list.ini";
    $filetochangeOpen = fopen($filetochange,"w") or die ("Error editing.");
    fputs($filetochangeOpen,$savedEdit);
    fclose($filetochangeOpen) or die ("Error Closing File!");
}
?>
```

HTML form

```
<form method=post action="mmtst.php">   
    <textarea rows="40" cols="60" name="filetest">
    <?
        // Implode CSS
        $filetochange = "../dashboard/list.ini";
        print (implode("",file($filetochange)));
    ?>
    </textarea><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="changefile">
</form>
```

Here I have a page that displays an INI file in a text box. What should happen is that when I click the submit button, the original file is opened, and fputs writes to the original with anything that is displayed in the txtbox. (the original file is set to permissions 777). However, nothing happens when the submit button is clicked, I have no idea what I am doing wrong, any suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: all write-related code is in a branch: `if($changefile)`, try dumping that, because by the looks of things: it might be an undefined variable, in which case the file is never opened, let alone written to. Also checkout [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/file_put_contents), replace the `put` with `get` to get it's reading counterpart. It doesn't require those extra lines of opening and closing a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simple, you have [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) disabled and you are trying to use it, this setting allow PHP to automatically define variables depending on received parameters from GET and POST data, but it's considered **insecure** and has been **deprecated**.

To access the values passed in a post for use the [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php) variable, for get use the [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php)

```
if( isset( $_POST["changefile"] ) ) {
```

In case you just want to check if a post form as been submitted you could `!empty($_POST)` and leave the submit button without name:

```
<?php //...
if( !empty($_POST) ) {
//...
?>
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes">
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for a

```
if ($changefile) {
```

You need to check for the $_POST version of the variable, the same you do for "filetest" variable, so you should for example...

```
if (isset($_POST["changefile"])) {
```

Otherwise the condition never returns true, and the code block doesn't get executed